# Not seeing any data in Xamarin CollectionView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, collectionview

I am learning Xamarin and I'm trying to make an app in which I can browse through some elements in a screen and after that, onclick of an element open a new screen. I tried using the flyout template for it, and for the first screen use the collectionview logic from the template. However, with the same logic, I am not seeing any data shown in my collection view. Here are my model, view, viewmodel and xaml and cs files.
Model:

```
public class VehicleMake
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Abrv { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             BackgroundColor="LightCoral"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VehicleProject.ViewModels" 
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:VehicleProject.Models" 
             x:DataType="local:VehicleMakeViewModel"
             x:Class="VehicleProject.Views.VehicleMakePage">
    <RefreshView x:DataType="local:VehicleMakeViewModel" Command="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <CollectionView x:Name="ItemsListView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding VehicleMakes}"
                SelectionMode="None">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout Padding="10" x:DataType="model:VehicleMake" BackgroundColor="White">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Id}" 
                           TextColor="White"
                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
                            Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
                            FontSize="16" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" 
                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                            Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                            FontSize="13" />
                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                                Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:VehicleModelViewModel}}, Path=ItemTapped}"      
                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                        </TapGestureRecognizer>
                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
    </RefreshView>
</ContentPage>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using VehicleProject.ViewModels;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace VehicleProject.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class VehicleMakePage : ContentPage
    {
        VehicleMakeViewModel _viewModel;
        public VehicleMakePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = _viewModel = new VehicleMakeViewModel();
        }
        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            _viewModel.OnAppearing();
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using VehicleProject.Models;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace VehicleProject.ViewModels
{
    public class VehicleMakeViewModel: BaseViewModel
    {
        private VehicleMake _selectedItem;
        public ObservableCollection<VehicleMake> VehicleMakes { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<VehicleMake>();
        public Command LoadItemsCommand { get; }
        public Command AddItemCommand { get; }
        public Command<VehicleMake> ItemTapped { get; }

        public VehicleMakeViewModel()
        {
            Title = "Vehicles";
            VehicleMakes = new ObservableCollection<VehicleMake>();
            LoadItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadItemsCommand());

            ItemTapped = new Command<VehicleMake>(OnItemSelected);

            AddItemCommand = new Command(OnAddItem);
        }

        async Task ExecuteLoadItemsCommand()
        {
            IsBusy = true;

            try
            {
                VehicleMakes.Clear();
                var vehicleMakes = await DataStore.GetItemsAsync(true);
                foreach (var vehicleMake in vehicleMakes)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(vehicleMake.Id);
                    VehicleMakes.Add(vehicleMake);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }
        public void OnAppearing()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            SelectedItem = null;
        }

        public VehicleMake SelectedItem
        {
            get => _selectedItem;
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, value);
                OnItemSelected(value);
            }
        }

        private async void OnAddItem(object obj)
        {
            //await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(NewItemPage));
        }

        async void OnItemSelected(VehicleMake item)
        {
            if (item == null)
                return;

            // This will push the ItemDetailPage onto the navigation stack
            //await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(ItemDetailPage)}?{nameof(ItemDetailViewModel.ItemId)}={item.Id}");
        }
    }
}
```

BaseViewModel:

```
public class BaseViewModel :  INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public IDataStore<VehicleMake> DataStore => DependencyService.Get<IDataStore<VehicleMake>>();

    bool isBusy = false;
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return isBusy; }
        set { SetProperty(ref isBusy, value); }
    }

    string title = string.Empty;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { SetProperty(ref title, value); }
    }

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value,
        [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "",
        Action onChanged = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
            return false;

        backingStore = value;
        onChanged?.Invoke();
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed == null)
            return;

        changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

IDataStore:

```
    public interface IDataStore<T>
        {
            Task<bool> AddItemAsync(T item);
            Task<bool> UpdateItemAsync(T item);
            Task<bool> DeleteItemAsync(string id);
            Task<T> GetItemAsync(string id);
            Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsAsync(bool forceRefresh = false);
        }
```

> MockVehicleMakeStore:

```
public class MockVehicleMakeStore : IDataStore<VehicleMake>
    {
        readonly List<VehicleMake> vehicleMakes;

        public MockVehicleMakeStore()
        {
            vehicleMakes = new List<VehicleMake>()
            {
                new VehicleMake { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name = "First item", Abrv="This is an item description." },
                new VehicleMake { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name = "Second item", Abrv="This is an item description." },
                new VehicleMake { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name = "Third item", Abrv="This is an item description." },
                new VehicleMake { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name = "Fourth item", Abrv="This is an item description." },
                new VehicleMake { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name = "Fifth item", Abrv="This is an item description." },
                new VehicleMake { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name = "Sixth item", Abrv="This is an item description." },
                new VehicleMake { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name = "Sixth item", Abrv="This is an item description." },
                new VehicleMake { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name = "Sixth item", Abrv="This is an item description." }

            };
        }
        public async Task<bool> AddItemAsync(VehicleMake item)
        {
            vehicleMakes.Add(item);

            return await Task.FromResult(true);
        }
        public async Task<bool> UpdateItemAsync(VehicleMake item)
        {
            var oldItem = vehicleMakes.Where((VehicleMake arg) => arg.Id == item.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            vehicleMakes.Remove(oldItem);
            vehicleMakes.Add(item);

            return await Task.FromResult(true);
        }

        public async Task<bool> DeleteItemAsync(string id)
        {
            var oldItem = vehicleMakes.Where((VehicleMake arg) => arg.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            vehicleMakes.Remove(oldItem);

            return await Task.FromResult(true);
        }

        public async Task<VehicleMake> GetItemAsync(string id)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(vehicleMakes.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id));
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<VehicleMake>> GetItemsAsync(bool forceRefresh = false)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(vehicleMakes);
        }
    }
```

The logic of my solution is the same of the one in the template, but it seems I'm overseeing something. Please help. Thank you

Comment: you are creating an instance of your VM but never loading any data

Comment: Okay so can you help me with that please?

Comment: execute `LoadItemsCommand` in the VM's `OnAppearing`

Comment: am I not already doing that in VehicleMakePage, as a Command binding in RefreshView?

Comment: is that executing automatically, or are you manually triggering the refresh?  Either way, you should verify that your VM **actually contains data**

Comment: I just tried swipe down gesture for a refresh and it didnt get any data either, being inexperienced here I would say I am probably overlooking something in the xaml file

Comment: you need to use the debugger to verify that you load command is being executed, and if it is actually loading the data

Comment: There I'm getting
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at VehicleProject.ViewModels.VehicleMakeViewModel.ExecuteLoadItemsCommand ()
Basically seems to be that line 
var vehicleMakes = await DataStore.GetItemsAsync(true); 
in VehicleMakeViewModel.cs is an issue

Comment: Something is null.  Figure out what it is and fix it.  The stack trace should show you exactly which line causes it.  This is basic C# debugging.

Comment: did you make any progress?

Comment: Sadly didn't catch much time so no. I will continue tomorrow

Comment: Hello, I added some more code (BaseViewModel, IDataStore and MockVehicleMakeStore,) which may help in seeing the issue. As I previously stated, I mostly used the template code and just rewrote it to match Item:VehicleMake analogy 1:1. I have changed the Binding to a hardcoded array and managed to see some data, so I would say the problem is maybe in BaseViewModel or MockVehicleMakeStoreClass. I am trying to learn and write code as I go, but the materials don't really lie well with me.
If you can see the problem, please do. 
Otherwise, thank you a lot for trying.

Comment: Good, you did a hardcoded test, and saw data. Next debugging step is to make the code as simple as you can, but still have the problem. The technique is to experiment with the "good" (but hardocded) version, and the "not working" code - strip out everything that doesn't seem to matter; try to isolate it down to one or a few lines of code. I mean, get the difference between a working hardcoded version and a broken version down to as few differences as you can. Re-do the code in question. Show hardcoded version that shows data, and show the exact code changes you make, that break it.

Comment: have you checked if `DataStore` is null?

Comment: I applied the same logic to a new project template for the third time and it works now. DataStore was not working properly because it was not initialized. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was that my DependencyService wasn't registered....
In app.xaml.cs I added the this line in its constructor, just after InitializeComponent();
DependencyService.Register();